# LINQ Groupping and Groupped Row Editing

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a Datatable That Looks like the Following

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Product Name  ║ Product Price ║ Product Group ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Skirt Red     ║            99 ║               ║
║ Jeans Blue    ║            49 ║               ║
║ Jeans Black   ║            49 ║               ║
║ Skirt Blue    ║            99 ║               ║
║ T-shirt White ║            20 ║               ║
║ T-shirt Green ║            20 ║               ║
║ Jeans Grey    ║            49 ║               ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

This is just an example Datatable and the Real Datatable has much more complex names and colors, as you can see there are simular products with different colors now using LINQ i want to make the Datatable Look like th following

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Product Name  ║ Product Price ║ Product Group ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Skirt Red     ║            99 ║             1 ║
║ Jeans Blue    ║            49 ║             2 ║
║ Jeans Black   ║            49 ║             2 ║
║ Skirt Blue    ║            99 ║             1 ║
║ T-shirt White ║            20 ║             3 ║
║ T-shirt Green ║            20 ║             3 ║
║ Jeans Grey    ║            49 ║             2 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

what defines a group? the price is the same and the name has nothing to do it.

i am new to LINQ and i wonder what would be the best approach to do this and the Datatable i am working with has about 112000 records

so bascily, i need to add products with same price to a group and Add a number beside each products the points to the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group the rows by price and loop through the groups setting the group field of each row in the group to a group number.

```
Dim query =
    From row in table.AsEnumerable
    Group row By Price = row.Field(Of Integer)("Product Price") Into ProductGroups = Group
Dim grpNumber = 1
For Each grp In query
    For Each row In grp.ProductGroups
        row.SetField("Product Group", grpNumber)
    Next
    grpNumber += 1
Next
```

Comment: can you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482339/vb-net-linq-group-by-multiple-columns