# VB.NET LINQ Group By Multiple Columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I have the following LINQ code which has a syntax error and i've no idea how to fix it

```
         Dim query =
        From row In mainDatatable.AsEnumerable

    'the syntax Error is in the following line
      Group row By new  { row.Field(Of Double)("cprice") , row.Field(Of Integer)("ccategory")} 
Into ProductGroups
    '**************************

                Dim grpNumber = 1
                For Each grp In query
                    For Each row In grp.ProductGroups
                        row.SetField("gnum", grpNumber)
                    Next
                    grpNumber += 1
                Next


            End Sub
```

so what am i doing wrong?

Here is how the table looks like and i want to group by the columns cprice and ccategory

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------+------+
| Product Name  | cprice        | ccategory | gnum |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+------+
| Skirt Red     |            99 |         1 |      |
| Jeans Blue    |            49 |         2 |      |
| Jeans Black   |            49 |         2 |      |
| Skirt Blue    |            99 |         1 |      |
| T-shirt White |            20 |         2 |      |
| T-shirt Green |            20 |         2 |      |
| Jeans Grey    |            49 |         2 |      |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: @GertArnold Arnold i get "Type With Expected"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
new with { Key.Price = row.Field(Of Double)("cprice") ,
           Key.Category = row.Field(Of Integer)("ccategory")
```

Uisng the `Key` modifier, this creates an anonymous type that implements equality based on [equality of its members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21703771/861716).

Comment: thanks,the first option worked, but i didn't get the results i expected, i expect the products that have the same cprice and same ccategory to be in a group , so i have 5800 rows it gave me 5800 groups!

Comment: Bit unexpected. Edited my answer.

Comment: For the record: in the mean time I've learned a bit more about equality of anonymous types in VB. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17259500/861716).

Comment: I could not get this to compile until I added `= Group` at the end of the statement

Comment: To use anonymous types in VB.NET you must use the `Key` modifier on the individual properties if you want to use them in a group-by\.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for spotting this.