# groupby doesn't work in linq ,result are same like input

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have an structure like this :

```
 public  class DebtCreditorRPT
    {
        [DisplayName("شناسه مشتری")]
        public string Memberid { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("نام ")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("مبلغ")]
        public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And values like these:

```
id      companyname       amount
1         a                12
2         b                13
1         a                14
```

And query like this using `groupby`:

```
  List<DebtCreditorRPT> result=new List<DebtCreditorRPT>();
```

[image]

The result that i need should be like this :

```
      companyname       amount
        a                26
        b                13
```

But it doesn't work .the result that i get from the above query is like input :

```
id      companyname       amount
1         a                12
2         b                13
1         a                14
```

why ?

Here is the real result that i get :

[image]
best regards

Comment: looks like you want to group by `Name`

Comment: No i need to groupby id

Comment: If you're grouping by id, then g.Key will be the id, not the name

Comment: you need to group by multiple properties at once-

Comment: so you mean i can't fetch the name to my result ?

Comment: I updated the values,i was wrong

Comment: If you group by id the there will only be a single value per group. No wonder the results look the same as the input.

Comment: Yes i updated the id values

Comment: I tried it in linqpad and worked as expected, both with grouping by `Name` and `Memberid`.

Comment: @NedStoyanov for proving my question i can put the pictures of my screen

Comment: @NedStoyanov please take a look at the pictures

Comment: I see the pic,  try and run the exact code in your question in a console app and see what you get. There may be an error in the part of your code that generates the picture.

Comment: There is no way you are getting the output you claim. Look at the Select: new { Name = ..., Amount = ...}. It Selects something with a Name and an Amount. There is no id in there. See it working: http://ideone.com/E9Ngy4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your query to:

```
  List<DebtCreditorRPT> result=new List<DebtCreditorRPT>();
  result.GroupBy(i=>i.Name).Select(g => new
              { 
                  Name = g.Key,
                  Amount = g.Sum(x => double.Parse(x.Amount))
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: i do this but the result is same like input ,should i save the result in another list?

Comment: If you are passing result as an input, make sure you use a ref parameter

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to group by id and name

```
result.GroupBy(i => new {i.Memberid, i.Name}).Select(g => new
          { 
              Name = g.Key.Name,
              Amount = g.Sum(x => double.Parse(x.Amount))
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Again my result is like input

Comment: How? Select returns something with 2 properties: {Name, Amount}. But I did find a different mistake. Ned Stoyanov's answer is correct

Comment: Please take a look at the picture in my post

Comment: I took a look at the picture. I don't know how this picture is generated, but it is not the output of the statement. Ned's answer will result in the output you claim you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you assume that GroupBy changes the input collection which it is applied to. This is not the case, it returns a new collection. (In your example, the grouped collection is not even of the same type as the input collection.)

Try this:

```
List<DebtCreditorRPT> groupedList = nonGroupedList.GroupBy(i => new 
  { 
    i.Memberid, 
    i.Name
  }).Select(g => new DebtCreditorRPT 
  {
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Amount = g.Sum(x => double.Parse(x.Amount)).ToString(), 
    Memberid = g.Key.Memberid
  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working in VB.Net, not C#, and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259500/98317) that unlike C#, VB.Net compares anonymous types by reference, not by the component values. To avoid this, you have to explicitly designate particular fields as keys using the `Key` keyword:

```
result.GroupBy(i => New With {Key i.Memberid, Key i.Name}).Select(g => new
{ 
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Amount = g.Sum(x => double.Parse(x.Amount))
}).ToList();
```

I see that you are working in C#, so I'm not sure why the suggested answers do not work for you. Linq seems to be using the *memory address* of the item for comparison (which will be different for every item even if the fields are exactly the same), not the individual elements.

To group in the manner you want you could use a string concatenated from the values of the key elements. This works because strings are compared by their contents, not by their addresses in memory:

```
result.GroupBy(i => i.Memberid.ToString() + i.Name).Select(g => new
{ 
    Name = g.FirstOrDefault().Name,
    Amount = g.Sum(x => double.Parse(x.Amount))
}).ToList();
```