# How do VB.NET anonymous types without key fields differ from C# anonymous types when compared?

Tags: c#, vb.net, anonymous-types

I'm scratching my head about this as I cannot understand why the following happens the way it does:

```
'//VB.NET
Dim product1 = New With {.Name = "paperclips", .Price = 1.29}
Dim product2 = New With {.Name = "paperclips", .Price = 1.29}

'compare product1 and product2 and you get false returned.

Dim product3 = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", Key .Price = 1.29}
Dim product4 = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", Key .Price = 1.29}

'compare product3 and product4 and you get true returned.

'//C#
var product5 = new {Name = "paperclips", Price = 1.29};
var product6 = new {Name = "paperclips", Price = 1.29};

//compare products 5 and 6 and you get true.
```

What is happening with products 1 and 2 that makes them not behave like products 5 and 6?

Comment: Maybe its caused by equals/== differences.. how you compare them? C# equals in anynomus classes returns true if fields are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C#, all properties of anonymous types behave as if they have the `Key` modifier in VB: the properties are read-only, and they're included in equality and hash code evaluation.

In VB, properties without the `Key` modifier are mutable, and are *not* used in the `Equals`/`GetHashCode` implementations.

From the [Anonymous Type Definition documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531354.aspx):

> If an anonymous type declaration contains at least one key property, the type definition overrides three members inherited from `Object`: `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, and `ToString`. If no key properties are declared, only `ToString` is overridden. The overrides provide the following functionality:
>
> - `Equals` returns True if two anonymous type instances are the same instance, or if they meet the following conditions:
>
>   - They have the same number of properties.
>   - The properties are declared in the same order, with the same names and the same inferred types. Name comparisons are not case-sensitive.
>   - At least one of the properties is a key property, and the Key keyword is applied to the same properties.
>   - Comparison of each corresponding pair of key properties returns True.
> - `GetHashcode` provides an appropriately unique `GetHashCode` algorithm. The algorithm uses only the key properties to compute the hash code.
> - `ToString` returns a string of concatenated property values, as shown in the following example. Both key and non-key properties are included.

Comment: Thanks Jon (Enjoying your 3rd edition btw). So does C# not have anonymous types with mutable properties? If so, any idea why it doesn't and VB.NET does?

Comment: @Rondles: No, C# doesn't support that. I'm not sure where the discrepancy comes from, I'm afraid.